# Apache virtualhosts set, ports listening, and this happening

Tags: apache-2.2

_: deniedPortAccess.longDesc

my 95 port shows as open
netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"
shows it
virtualhosts set, and ports.conf listening
should I restart pc
maybe server?

http://postimg.org/image/l3midiau1/

EDIT:
also what is this port used for?  ::1:631 apache listening

I restarted server, and port 95 is still listening but this doesn't work `http://84.237.249.24:95/`

LAST EDIT (?)

OK, now tell me how others will see with there firefox browsers having settings like that?

Comment: Try to repair this, maybe the moderator will remove this hold.

Comment: Hi, questions need to be _complete_ and _in English_.

Comment: Why are you trying to use port 95 here?

Comment: free space for something

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.security.ports.banned.override

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Firefox restricts a number of ports from access. To get around this, you have to remove port 95 from the banned ports list by modifying `Network.security.ports.banned.override` in your `about:config`.

For further information, see: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.security.ports.banned.override

I don't have Firefox personally so I can't provide a screenshot, though.

Edit: OP pointed out Chrome, and the solution for Chrome is appending `--explicitly-allowed-ports=95` to your shortcut target.

Edit 2: As a result of discussion, always avoid commonly-used or reserved ports. [This](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/PortBanning.html) page has a list Firefox uses (may be out of date) but the general idea is to use above 1024.

Comment: I never knew that - thank you!  Also, have an upvote.

Comment: but chrome does this (by saying it's lost), too and I don't have such bolean.

Comment: @RonaldsMazītis Chrome is a bit funkier. Right-click the shortcut you use for Chrome and append this to the end of the "Target": `--explicitly-allowed-ports=95`

Comment: @RonaldsMazītis Better yet, don't use this port at all. Use the default port of 80, or an unregistered port.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Fair enough. :)

Comment: nothing changes when Network.security.ports.banned.override is true or false..

Comment: @RonaldsMazītis Set it to "true", then edit the list above it (should be just `network.security.ports.banned` and remove 95 from it.

Comment: what list, there is no list for bolean.

Comment: network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist;false ? also bolean

Comment: @RonaldsMazītis See: http://blog.christoffer.me/post/2012-02-20-how-to-remove-firefoxs-this-address-is-restricted/

Comment: Thanks, Nathan C, now I see it, but do others?

Comment: They probably don't so your answer to this discussion is sad and something like pre-built port blocks in major browsers, concerns my inner feeling of freedom to make as many individual html/php/javascript or any other objects in browser on my Apache environment. Maybe this happens only with apache? or I'm mistaking something from this all.

Comment: @RonaldsMazītis The browsers block common ports for security reason. This has nothing to do with Apache, but rather your choice of port.

Comment: Please suggest ports that work on every browser :)

Comment: @RonaldsMazītis Anything above 1024 basically. See: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/PortBanning.html